# Max open files (MySQL 5.0 on FreeBSD 7.0)

Tags: mysql, freebsd, ulimit

I'm getting "Can't open file: './databasename/tablename.frm' (errno: 24)" errors from MySQL but as far as I can tell, I've set the necessary limits far higher than I need.

Other than the `kern.maxfiles` and `kern.maxfilesperproc` sysctls and the `open_files_limit` MySQL variable, are there any other limits which would be kicking in and causing this?

```
$ mysql -u root -p -e 'SHOW STATUS' | grep '^Open'
Enter password: 
Open_files  356
Open_streams    0
Open_tables 245
Opened_tables   0

$ mysql -u root -p -e 'SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES' | grep 'open_files_limit'
Enter password: 
open_files_limit    18000

$ sysctl -a | grep kern.maxfiles
kern.maxfiles: 20000
kern.maxfilesperproc: 18000

$ limits -n -U mysql
Resource limits for class default:
  openfiles        infinity
```

Comment: what shows `sysctl kern.openfiles` ?

Comment: Right now, 867 and we're over 50% of average peak queries per second. 

I haven't been able to trap the value of it when the failure occurs (I'm wary of shelling out inside the vBulletin error handler), but I have munin running and the open_files plugin records kern.maxfiles and kern.openfiles every 5 minutes. Peak for kern.openfiles is approx 2000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue looks more like a bug than bumping into a limit.
Only suggestion is to update to latest stable MySQL version, or even to FreeBSD 7.2 (they higher almost all limits on FreeBSD 7.2 amd64)

Comment: The machine in question is a replication slave so I'm hesitant to upgrade past 5.0 without upgrading the master and other slaves as well. Since it's in production, I can't afford the downtime. As for FreeBSD 7.2, there's a bug (PR:135673) which we ran into on another slave. We patched it out, but the patch only reduces the frequency of the lockups, not eliminate them. Thanks for the suggestions though, they may be worth re-examining.

Answer (score 0):

what is your `max_connections` Setting? For every connection one (or more) files are to be opened. Try to reduce. Also `table_cache` Setting can influence the number of open files. See [mysql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/not-enough-file-handles.html) for more help.

CU, arnep

Comment: Both max_connections and table_cache have been tuned to be as small as possible while leaving us some headroom for spikes. Thanks for the answer.